# TYPO3 Support Times: What exactly means "extended support"?

Tags: typo3, updates

The support times in TYPO3 are "Regular Maintenance", "Priority Bugfixes" and "Extended Support" as you can see in the roadmap: https://typo3.org/cms/roadmap/

1. What exactly is the difference between the "Priority Bugfixes" and "Extended Support" times?
2. Is it required to change to the next major version   before the "Extended Support" time starts?

Answer (score 7):

Once a LTS release is made, the TYPO3 community / core mergers are fixing bugs for (roughly) 18 months, this also includes security bugfixes - for free.

After that, another 18 months we'll only add important / priority bugfixes. We chose to avoid "important" and used "priority" as everything is important if it is in one persons' project. Anything related to security, browser support or invalid data storage is considered "priority".

Example:

- 9.5 LTS released in October 2018
- Any kind of bugfixes for 18 months (until April 2020)
- Any kind of security or browser issues for another 18 months (until October 2021)

Then the official "free" support by the TYPO3 runs out. You can stay on this LTS version, but you might be open for being hacked (however, there are more factors to this than just the LTS version of TYPO3). In any case, no fixes, no releases, no support is given for this version anymore.

You have 3 years of free support with an LTS version.

Extended Support (labelled ELTS) is a special paid offering by TYPO3.com (https://typo3.com/products/extended-support) for projects that cannot (yet) update to the next major. There are usually some external factors related to this (PHP version too old on the servers, no budget for update, relaunch coming the year after). You can find more details on the typo3.com website. I *think* that one can choose for an ELTS of 1-3 years. This means you can get a total of 6 years of support for an LTS version. Three years for free and up to three additional years by a paid service.

Extended Support can also be an important for larger projects to choose TYPO3 in the beginning so it is ensured (although paid) that support for a long time is given - similar to what Red Hat (RHEL) is offering for their linux distribution.

Comment: Answering your second question: This is not required

Answer (score 2):

**Regular Maintenance**
free of charge
Version is fully supported
18 months (until next LTS release)

**Priority Bugfixes**
free of charge
Version is supported with security and critical fixes
18 months (until the next but one LTS release)

**Extended Support**
paid program offered by TYPO3 GmbH
to extend the secure lifetime of a TYPO3 instance
another 36 months
[More information](https://typo3.com/products/extended-support)

An LTS release of TYPO3 is therefore officially supported 3 years after release. This will be followed by another 3 years in which the support can be purchased from TYPO3 GmbH.

Of course it is always advisable to update after a new LTS release (18 months after LTS release). The next point in time would be the next but one LTS release, since no free support will be offered from this point on (36 months after LTS release). The latest time for an update is the end of Extended Support. (6 years after LTS release)

Of course it is not obligatory to perform the update, but it is advisable for at least security reasons.